# Database reccomendation for retrival of data (strings, int and float) with python

Tags: database, mysql, sql, mongodb, sqlite

I'm looking for recommendation for the following:

I currently have approximately 10 Million csv file each with the following identical data structure as file attached:

[image: Typical data structure]

I want to transfer all this data from the csv files into a database.

From the said database I want to be able to retrieve with Python in the fastest way possible all the ID for the files matching the search criteria which I am going to insert.

The criteria will be based on either the average or median from the "Product Quantity" or "Product Price".

An example of typical queries would be:

- Retrieve from the entire database all ID which have AVG Product Quantity minor or equal to 50.

or

- Retrieve from the entire database all ID which have AVG Product Price for Product No. from 1 to 10, below or equal to 30 USD?

What is the best database to do this? SQL, Mysql, SqlLite, MongoDB, Orcale or any other?